Weird issue with pgfplots legend deleting curly brace
When compiling the following
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1]
        \addplot { ifthenelse(x < 0, 0, x) };
        \legend{$\text{ReLU}(x):=\max\{0, x\}$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

with TeXLive 2023, I get the following error:
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\pgfplots@already@computed@legend@node ...max \{0}
                                                  ;\\};
l.13     \end{axis}
                   
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.13     \end{axis}
                   
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.

The error says that it has "deleted a group-closing symbol" which I think it shouldn't, because using just $\text{ReLU}(x):=\max\{0, x\}$ on its own in text works fine.
What exactly is the problem here, and how can I resolve it or tell it to not delete the }?

pgfplots seems to dislike the ,  in this place, probably because it's used as a delimiter between options. // Syntactically pgfplots accepts backslashing it, at least here: $x := (0 \, x)$   AND it doesn't print it ... // Suggestion: Find a better way to express what you want to tell via the legend.

@MS-SPO using \, instead of , works, but it changes the meaning, as \, is just a small space ... I could just put the whole thing in the caption of course, I'm just wondering why this wouldn't work (similarly, \max(0, x) doesn't work as well, probably for exactly the same reason).

Right. Didn't I express it? My bad. // Without testing it, nodes usually accept any valid LaTeX code (with some limitations). So you could place a node instead of a legend. This at least decouples syntactical problems.

Please see my update. (And yes, to preserve the blue line and dot, you could do some tricks ... if really needed)

As always when hiding a tex delimiter within an argument you can use a {} group as the delimiter is only recognised at the top level so for example
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=-1:1]
        \addplot { ifthenelse(x < 0, 0, x) };
        \legend{${\text{ReLU}(x):=\max\{0, x\}}$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



I tried \legend{{$...$}} but didn't realise the { and } go inside math-mode - cheers, this works!

@user20478285 the pgfplot legend macro could be coded a bit more carefully not to drop the brace group if it is the whole argument but it doesn't (I tried that first as well:-) arguably that's a bug but it complicates the code for an edge case so it may be classed as a feature: the primitive tex behaviour is to drop a brace group that is the whole argument, so it can be tricky to catch all cases.

Update: Here's a way to place a node, which accepts text pgfplot would preceive "being weird", WITHOUT any further styling, like drawing its shape etc.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-1:1,
        legend style={
            at={(0.05,.95)},
            anchor=north west,
        },
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y(x),
    ]
        \addplot { ifthenelse(x < 0, 0, x) };
        \legend{
            $y(x) := (x \le 0 \quad ? \quad 0 : x)$
        }
        \node[anchor=west] 
            at (axis cs:-1.1,.4) {$\text{ReLU}(x):=\max\{0, x\}$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Here's a Perlish way to do it, just to express the if-then-else phrase, as syntax seems to be tricky here:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-1:1,
        legend style={
            at={(0.05,.95)},
            anchor=north west,
        },
        xlabel=x,
        ylabel=y(x),
    ]
        \addplot { ifthenelse(x < 0, 0, x) };
        \legend{
            $y(x) := (x \le 0 \quad ? \quad 0 : x)$
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


